# Sending authentication sms using Google

Tags: authentication, sms

i have a question.
Is it posible to do something like this:
I open a website and have an inputbox to type special code.
In the same time I receive an sms from google(like in 2-way auth) with code(it's sending immediately as the site loads).
I type received code, press "Check" and if code is good then some action, but when not some alert being displayed.

The main question is: Is it possible to receive sms from google to authorizate an access?